# New Firebase failed: First argument must be a valid firebase URL and the path can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"

Tags: javascript, firebase

I am using Firebase to check presence, but the console throws up the following error:

```
New Firebase failed: First argument must be a valid firebase URL and the path can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]".
```

the following is the code:

```
new Firebase("https://123654789.firebaseio.com/123654/.info/connected").on('value', function(connectedSnap) {
  console.log(connectedSnap.val());
  if (connectedSnap.val() === true) {
    alert('I am connected!');
  } else {
    /* we're disconnected! */
    alert('not connected!');
  }
});
```

Comment: `can't contain "."`, and you have `.info`... so.... learn to read the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.info/connected` path only exists on the top-level of your Firebase data. You cannot access it from child nodes.

So change

```
new Firebase("https://123654789.firebaseio.com/123654/.info/connected")
```

To

```
new Firebase("https://123654789.firebaseio.com/.info/connected")
```

And the error message will disappear.

Comment: Thanks Frank for rescuing me !