# Testing firebase connection with .info/connected

Tags: firebase

I am trying to test a connection based on the answer in [Detect if Firebase connection is lost/regained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11351689/detect-if-firebase-connection-is-lost-regained)

I tried:

```
var testRef=new Firebase('https://flickering-heat-528.firebaseio.com/test');

testRef.child('.info/connected').on('value', function(connectedSnap) {
  if (connectedSnap.val() === true) {
    alert('* we\'re connected! *');
  } else {
    alert('* we\'re disconnected! *');
  }
});
```

see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b1wtq3gj/)

but I get: Uncaught Error: Firebase.child failed: First argument was an invalid path: ".info/connected". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"

what's wrong ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New Firebase failed: First argument must be a valid firebase URL and the path can't contain ".", "#", "$", "\[", or "\]"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31518707/new-firebase-failed-first-argument-must-be-a-valid-firebase-url-and-the-path-ca)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only use `.info/connect` directly as a child under the root, so:

```
var testRef=new Firebase('https://flickering-heat-528.firebaseio.com/'); // I removed 'test' here

testRef.child('.info/connected').on('value', function(connectedSnap) {
  if (connectedSnap.val() === true) {
    alert('* we\'re connected! *');
  } else {
    alert('* we\'re disconnected! *');
  }
});
```